# CSS nth-child() working strange?

Tags: html, css, magento, fieldset

There is a HTML structure with two `fieldset`, like in the jsfiddle example below. The following CSS lines

```
#aboutus > fieldset:nth-child(2) li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

can affect to the second `fieldset`'s elements in jsfiddle, but on the page should add this for the resullt:

```
#aboutus > fieldset:nth-child(4) li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

there are no 4th fieldset, but only in this case apply the `text-align: left;` to the object (`li`).

http://jsfiddle.net/EQPTS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `nth-of-type` not `nth-child`, the former considers the element type, the latter its position and eligibility.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQPTS/2/)

[**`nth-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

> The :nth-of-type CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1
>   siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree,
>   for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>   See :nth-child for a more thorough description of the syntax of its
>   argument. This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector if you
>   want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag no matter where
>   it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags appear
>   before it.

[**`nth-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive
>   or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>
> This can more clearly be described this way: the matching element is
>   the bth child of an element after all its children have been split
>   into groups of a elements each.

Answer (score 2):

The `nth-child` selector, selects nth element, with the same type of the selector. 2nd child is the first fieldset. You need to use `nth-of-type` and not `nth-child`.

```css
#aboutus li {
    text-align: right;
}
#aboutus > fieldset:nth-of-type(2) li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This works for you.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/EQPTS/1/